# Where to get ACM references for MS Word?

Tags: citations, acm

Does someone know where to get the correctly formatted *ACM references* for submissions to ACM? Google Scholar and dl.acm.org don't seem to provide the correct formatting.

Comment: Is [this](http://www.acm.org/publications/word_style/word-style-toc/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Please use LaTeX.

Comment: its too late to switch to latex :/

Comment: @MadJack No then I would have to write them on my own but this is error prone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managing references can be a tedious task, especially at the proof-reading step of a paper and the usage of software that keeps track of your paper/references library (e.g. EndNote or BiBDesk) can be strongly recommended.

With such software you can have all your references in your paper formated accordingly and automatically to the style that either you choose or the conference/journal wants.

In MS Word there is an option where you can integrate EndNote, insert references and have an automated formating and arrangement/re-arrangement. Integration is done automatically for EndNote and MS Word, just when you install both of software.

ACM style quide can be found [here](http://www.acm.org/publications/word_style/word-style-toc/).

Comment: yeah I tried it with EndNote but the style looks different as well.

Comment: I cannot seem to find MS Word template for the [new ACM International Conference Proceedings Series format](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template). MS Word template appears not updated. E.g. the referencing style in the [MS Word template](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/article-templates/pubform.docx) is different from that in the [sample PDF](https://www.acm.org/binaries/content/assets/publications/article-templates/sig-alternate-sample.pdf).